# Sliding div out with css and jquery without triggering scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've been wrestling with this for way too long.

Problem: I'm trying to make the image slide off of screen when the button is pressed, which I have successfully done, but not adequately. There are two problems:

- I don't want to hide overflow on the body to hide the horizontal scroll being triggered when the div moves off the screen.
- When I click on the button for a second time, I want the div to slide in from the right back to the original position. I haven't been able to figure this one out. I know I can do it, but creating another css class, but I know there has to be an easier way.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexflores67/6mnuj2jz/19/#&togetherjs=kJQH77iEqM)

CSS:

```
#abs {
position: absolute; 
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-color: grey;
left: 0;
top:0;
transition: transform 3s;
}

.open {
  transform: translateX(1050px);
 }

.hide {
   display: none;
 }

 p {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

JS:

```
  $('#clickMe').on('click', function(){
    $('#abs').toggleClass('open');
    if($("#abs").hasClass("open")) { 
        setTimeout(
        function() {
            $("#abs").hide();
        },
        2500);
} else {
    $("#abs").show();
}
})
```

Comment: For avoid horizontal scrolbar try to add `overflow: hidden` to `.test` in css (in JSFiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Please refer to the fiddle.https://jsfiddle.net/cdx7zeo2/1/

I modified your code to use jQuery animate.

```
$('#clickMe').on('click', function(){
        var right = parseInt($('#abs').css('left'));
    console.log(right);
    if(right === 0){
       $( "#abs" ).animate({
        left:'2500px'
        }, 1500);
    }else{
       $( "#abs" ).animate({
          left:'0px'
      }, 1500);
    }
})
```

Also modified the id test to have overflow-y hidden, so that you don't need to tough overflow property of body. Note, here we are not using open class anymore.

```
#test {
  position: relative; 
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black; 
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
```